# VBA code override formulas within cell (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

```
'Make Schedule C Total Expenses line items always negative
    If Target.Address = "$I$25" Or Target.Address = "$L$25" Or Target.Address = "$O$25" Or Target.Address = "$R$25" _
    Or Target.Address = "$I$45" Or Target.Address = "$L$45" Or Target.Address = "$O$45" Or Target.Address = "$R$45" _
    Or Target.Address = "$I$65" Or Target.Address = "$L$65" Or Target.Address = "$O$65" Or Target.Address = "$R$65" _
    Or Target.Address = "$I$85" Or Target.Address = "$L$85" Or Target.Address = "$O$85" Or Target.Address = "$R$85" _
    Or Target.Address = "$I$105" Or Target.Address = "$L$105" Or Target.Address = "$O$105" Or Target.Address = "$R$105" Then
        If Target.Value > 0 Then
            Target.Value = 0 - Target.Value
        End If
    End If
```

I want to convert the values in those ranges to negative.  However, the code would overwrite my formulas in the cell and replaces it with a static value.

my formula is:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(F21=1,F21=2,F21=3,F21=4,F21=5),IF('PFS - Personal CF Report'!J$4=1040,INDEX(PFS1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("C 28",PFS1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0),0),0)
```

the code would replace the formula for a static value of '12560'.  I need the formula to stay.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: `Target.Formula = "=0 -" &  mid(Target.formula,2)`

Comment: Scott has the right answer. For further explanation, by using Target.Value, you are telling Excel to put in exactly that value. That's why you're getting static values. By using Target.Formula, you will overwrite the formula with a new one. I have a question for you: do you need to use VBA? It seems it would be easier just to replace the existing Excel formulas in those cells with `=-ABS([exiting formula here])` and not even have to use VBA.

Comment: @ScottCraner Won't that be a circular reference? Target.Formula referencing itself?

Comment: @Spidey not a circular reference but if it is in a Worksheet_Change event and the event were not disabled then it would iterate till Excel crashed, but this would have already been happening with the existing code so I assumed that the OP had already done that.  Without more code it is hard to say.  But it is similar to doing `a=a+1` The right side resolves first then puts that into the variable/cell.

Comment: @Trashman I could've used =-ABS([exiting formula here]) and I would have done so.  However, I don't have the formula in place yet,  I am still editing the worksheet.  The code is from a previous person who was working on the worksheet.  

Thank you for the help guys!!! I've learned a lot and will definitely remember this!

Comment: @Trashman actually you're right.  It would be easier to just use -ABS([exiting formula here]) now that I am going through it.  Thank you for the advice!